# How to fetch older files first from Directory using c#?

Tags: c#

I have one folder name called `IncomingFiles`. Inside that folder I have multiple file. Thouse files for only .xml.

Below are list of files under `IncomingFiles` folder with different TimeStamp:

E.g:

```
+-------------------+---------------------+---------------+
|Name               | Date Modifided      | Type          |
+-------------------+---------------------+---------------+
| test4.xml         | 23/6/2016 12:30 PM  | XML Document  |
| test3.xml         | 23/6/2016 12:20 PM  | XML Document  |
| test2.xml         | 23/6/2016 12:10 PM  | XML Document  |
| test1.xml         | 23/6/2016 12:00 PM  | XML Document  |
+-------------------+---------------------+---------------+
```

I have to fetch files based on older time.

E.g:

```
First i have to fetch  below file:
test1.xml  
Second I have to fetch below file:
test2.xml
Third I have to fetch below file:
test3.xml
Fourth I have to fetch below file:
test4.xml
```

How to do that. Please helo me to solve.

Comment: What is the problem with ordering the list according to DATE?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

using linq sorted by `LastWriteTime` and only `.xml` files:

```
DirectoryInfo dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo("IncomingFiles");
List<FileInfo> files = dirInfo.GetFiles()
    .Where(f => f.Extension == ".xml")        
    .OrderBy(f => f.LastWriteTime)
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

Use linq

```
var dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo("yourpath");
var files = dirInfo.GetFiles().OrderBy(f => f.CreationTime);
```

Comment: it would be more accurate if you use `"*.xml", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly` as parameters to the `GetFiles` method

Comment: Note that OP needs *date modified*, not *creation time*

Comment: @ardila that is not clear. Oldest file to me sounds like created. not least recent modified.

Comment: @MauriceStam I'd agree with you had that statement not been preceded by a table with a *Date modified* column. If it's not clear, that's what the comments are for

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Directory.GetFiles`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.getfiles(v=vs.110).aspx) to list the file paths inside the specified directory. which allows you to specify the `SearchPatterns` and `SearchOption`. Then you have to use the LINQ Extension method `.OrderBy` to sort it on the basics of their `LastWriteTime`.

```
  var sortedFiles = Directory.GetFiles("path_here", "*.xml", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
                             .OrderBy(x => new FileInfo(x).LastWriteTime);
```